# Inject HTML string from database into NextJS app/component to accelerate SSR

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a Next.js application running version 13.4.19, and I'm aiming to enhance its performance. Specifically, I'm interested in incorporating pre-rendered HTML sourced from my database into certain components of certain pages.

Is there a better way to do that than using the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` prop? Is there any recommended way to do this kind of things?

I could not find a lot of content about that on the web.

Thanks a lot.